# php set lines in a text file to an array value

Tags: php, arrays

Im looking to do something like the following

```
$file = ('file.txt');
$fopen($file);
```

then read each line from the file individually and set it as a specific array

like so

```
read $file get $line1 set as $array[0]
read $file get $line2 set as $array[1]
read $file get $line3 set as $array[2]
```

I would like to use these arrays created from the lines on the text file IN PLAIN TEXT like this:

```
$urlout = file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=$line1");
echo $urlout;
$urlout2 = file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=$line2");
echo $urlout2;
$urlout3 = file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=$line3");
echo $urlout3;
```

So if the array were 123.22.11.22 the link would look like this:

```
$line1 = array[0] (123.22.11.22)
$urlout = file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=$line1");
echo $urlout;
```

and the result would be

Info for 123.22.11.22
more info
some more

Comment: I am not getting what error you are seeing or where you stucked up ..

Comment: Basically what im trying to accomplish is pulling each line of text and outputting that line to a file_get_contents value and then return the result

Comment: Your logic explained above is right. You are almost there to answer. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to insert a "\n" separator upon inserting into the text file, then removing it after the first result was called

```
$lines = file("geo.txt");
for($i=0 ; $i<count($lines); $i=($i+2) )
{
echo file_get_contents("https://test.com/api/GEO.php?info=".$lines[$i]);

$lolz = file_get_contents("https://test.com/api/GEO.php?info=".$lines[($i + 1)]);
$lolz = str_replace(" \n", '', $lolz);
echo "<br>".$lolz;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Modified answer as per the change indicated by the user :

Reading 2 lines on each loop..

```
$lines = file("file.txt");
for($i=0 ; $i<count($lines); $i=($i+2) )
{
    echo file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=".$lines[$i]);
    echo file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=".$lines[($i + 1)]);
}
```

**Imp Note** : A URL can be used as a filename with `file_get_contents()` function, only  if the [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled.

Comment: That still for some reason is only outputting the first line :(

Basically there are 2 IP's in a text file and i want to read from the file and set the IP on the first line to $line1 and set the second to $line2 so on and so forth

Comment: I have a syntax error in 
echo file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=$lines[($i + 1)]");

Comment: Try now. $lines[] should not be in quotes

Comment: Hmm still having issues, maybe you can check what im doing wrong?

    http://pastebin.com/Z0Nbp2a9

The output can be seen http://shut-em-down.com/Soap/skyperesolver.php as of
current type in parra1995 and hit resolve.

Comment: Where it says "Invalid IP address or Domain" should be showing the geo info for the first IP address :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/?=$line");
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```